# Use an escaped percent sign in TeX and MathJax with pandoc markdown

Tags: latex, pandoc, mathjax

It's easy to write TeX equations in Markdown documents and convert them to actual typeset equations [using pandoc](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#math) (version 1.18), either in a PDF document (through LaTeX) or an HTML document (through MathJax): surround math in `$...$` for inline equations and `$$...$$` for block equations.

However, there seems to be a discrepancy between MathJax and TeX syntax with special characters like `%`. For instance, consider this sample document:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 

$$\text{\% change} = \frac{x_2 - x_1}{x_1} \times 100$$

Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
```

Converting this to PDF via LaTeX using the command

```
pandoc test.md -o test.pdf
```

correctly produces an unescaped percent sign:

[image: tex output]

However, converting the same document to HTML with MathJax, using the command

```
pandoc test.md -s --mathjax -o test.html
```

incorrectly produces an escaped percent sign:

[image: html output]

For now, I've been manually escaping/unescaping percent signs before converting my documents to PDF/HTML, which seems to defeat the purpose of having a master Markdown document that can convert to any format.

What is the correct way to handle escaped percent signs in both TeX and MathJax? Is there a setting in MathJax that allows special characters to be escaped? Do I need to tell LaTeX to accept unescaped percent signs in math mode?

Comment: this sounds like a bug in MathJax, are you using the latest version?

Comment: This happens in the current version, 2.7.1: https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/releases/tag/2.7.1

Comment: The extraneous escape slash appears on the live demo at the main MathJax site too: https://www.mathjax.org/#modal-livedemo. This makes me think it's not necessarily a bug, but by design (and on this forum, it sounds like % is *not* treated a special, escapable character: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mathjax-users/Ed1nKT-xtAE/IKvO_NZ9e1QJ)

Comment: probably has something to do with the `\text{}` it's in... why not use `\percent` instead?

Comment: For the record, MathJax does not support macros inside `\text{}` (with the sole exception of `$` to re-enter math mode), see [the documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html?highlight=There%20are%20two%20exception%20to%20this%20rule).

Comment: MathJax also doesn't appear to support `\percent` in general. But moving the `\%` out of `\text{}` fixes it: `$$\%\text{ change}$$`

Answer (score 1):

(I know this is not tagged under [R] but I know Andrew is an avid R and Rmarkdown user, so I hope this will suffice.)

This is possible using Rmarkdown and knitr. The script below produces the desired outputs when rendered with `rmarkdown::render`. I also create a [gist of the script](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dantonnoriega/eab3851ab60e1f35fb17afbf3c0a4cd4/raw/7209c89a0c53744586a0425d45ad51cdfa7d4fe4/percent_sign_latex_html.rmd).

````
---
title: TEST
output:
    pdf_document:
        latex_engine: xelatex
    html_document:
        fig_caption: true
---

```{r, echo = FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
  collapse = TRUE,
  echo = TRUE,
  cache = FALSE,
  comment = "#>",
  fig.path = "fig-",
  fig.pos = "h"
)

# this will check what the output format is going to be
getOutputFormat <- function() {
  knitr::opts_knit$get("rmarkdown.pandoc.to")
}
```


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 

```{r, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE, echo=FALSE, eval=TRUE, results='asis'}
s <- "$$\\text{\\% change} = \\frac{x_2 - x_1}{x_1} \\times 100$$"
if(getOutputFormat() == 'html') s <- gsub('\\\\%', '%', s) # dont escape if html
knitr::asis_output(s)
```

Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
````